# simplify multiple sql queries different variable

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I am trying to better automate my queries so I don't have to change the table name and where clause each time. Right now this is what I do:

Years 2014, 2013, etc. I might out these variables into a table. Also doing this on Oracle.
Colors: Red, Green, etc

```
    select count(*) from Apples_2014
    where Type = 'Red'
    ;
    select count(*) from Apples_2014
    where Type = 'Green'
    ;
    select count(*) from Apples_2013
    where Type = 'Red'
    ;
    select count(*) from Apples_2013
    where Type = 'Green'
;
```

Is there a simpler way to do this so I have only one query and then it gets run multiple times but with the different parameters?

Also through some research I saw I can use && which then creates a popup each time in Toad. This isn't really efficient though but its kinda works.

Comment: Where are you running the queries from, and where does the year and colour come from?

Comment: I am running them from Toad. I highlight all those queries and press F5. It then gives me the count for each query at once. The year is basically the different tables in the DB. So there is already a table for each year. Maybe it could loop through all tables with the Apples_ in it. The color comes from another Table that is called Apple_Types. So in the Apple types table there is a column called Types which contains the different colors.

Comment: You could join to the `apple_types` table to avoid having to enter each colour manually. A table per year sounds like a data model problem; you really need to query them separately unless you want to get into dynamic SQL, but you could union then results so there is just one statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ADDITION** (original answer below.  Editing after seeing your comment on your post.)

Sounds like you actually want do to grouping.

Running something like the below will give counts for all tables and all values at once in a single result set.

```
      select count(*) as total, 'TABLENAME' as tablename, value
      from Tablename
      group by value;
      UNION ALL
      select count(*) as total, 'TABLENAME2' as tablename, value
      from Tablename2
      group by value
```

*******************************************************88
**Original answer:**

you can use bind variables in Oracle - it will then prompt for each value.

```
select count(*) from TABLE
    where Type = :value
```

assuming your table structures are very similar, you can union and add a paramater to handle the table name changes without switching to use dynamic sql (dynamic sql is just writing it as a concatenated string - not very efficient.).

So like this....

```
select total
from (
      select count(*) as total, 'TABLENAME' as tablename
      from Tablename
      where type = :value;
      UNION ALL
      select count(*) as total, 'TABLENAME2' as tablename
      from Tablename2
      where type = :value
     ) a
where a.tablename = :tablename
```